# Cron job is wokring fine but new cron logs are not adding in cron log file

Tags: linux, centos, logging, cron

i mistakely press wq! in cron log file located /var/log/cron now new logs are not updateing in cron log file i serach many thing like

- remove cron file and touch /var/log/cron  Steel not updateing
- waiting for 1 day to auto regenerateing the cron log file.

Please Guide me How to resolve that issue asap.
System we are using centos 7 Ubentu / linux

Comment: did you restart crond?